# Is there a usable CLI interface to libsodium?

Tags: command-line, cryptography

I am hoping to ditch PGP in favor of a simpler and more modern tool. I understand that libsodium implements symmetric key encryption, non-repudiable signing (I think), authenticated (repudiable) encryption, and anonymous encryption; that covers all of my use cases. But I can't begin using it as a replacement or recommend it to others unless there's a CLI interface.

Comment: Did you end up solving this requirement?